# Update Table data using variables depending on other tables

Tags: mysql

Suppose the following tables:

```
faculty:
+----+--------+
| id | headFK |
+----+--------+

department:
+----+----------+--------+
| id | facultyFK| headFK |
+----+----------+--------+

teacher:
+----+--------------+-------+
| id | departmentFK | chief |
+----+--------------+-------+
```

What is the best way to go through each row of teacher. Save some column values as variables (suppose: `id`, `departmentFK`) to use it in further Queries (Update to be specific)

My aim is to set up subordinations of teacher which is like this chain `'Faculty Head' > 'Department Head' > 'Teacher'`

Formally it should look like:

```
FOR EACH ROW IN teacher
{
    Set curDepartment = Current.departmentFK;
    Set curTeacher = Current.id;
    Set curFaculty = (Query to get faculty);
    Set FacultyHead = (Query to get current faculty head by var curFaculty );
    Set departmentHead = (Query to get current department head by var curDepartment );

    (Query to update teacher.chief with conditions using variable acquired before)
}
```

Could you please tell the way (Procedures, Functions or ordinary queries) how can I do it because I've never had experience with procedures or local variables in MySQL and I cannot figure out how can I implement it

PS: I'm not asking to write code (that would be too much I think) but an approach to implement it

**Update**

Thanks to the Rick James's note I came up with the following solution:

```
UPDATE teacher
    JOIN department ON teacher.DepFR = department.DepPK
    JOIN faculty ON department.FacFK = faculty.FacPK
SET teacher.ChiefFK = CASE
    WHEN teacher.TchPK = faculty.DeanFK THEN NULL
    WHEN teacher.TchPK = department.HeadFK THEN faculty.DeanFK
    ELSE department.HeadFK
END;
```

Is it a good way of doing it?

Comment: Is there a `head` table (that these `headFK` are referencing)?

Comment: @ypercube, `headFK` is referencing `teacher` table. So as `chief`

Comment: Do you have to do it in SQL? Procedural code is much simpler to write in some procedural language.

Comment: @jkavalik Yes. I must do it in SQL (MySQL). And efficiency does not matter in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a no-no to have redundant data.

Instead, use `JOIN` when doing the `SELECT`; this will let you dynamically get the faculty, faculty_head, etc.

Learn about `JOIN`.

Comment: But in the end I will need to update the record in teacher. And this update will depend on the head of faculty, head of department. Which means that I will need to compare specific teacher and heads of department and faculty.
Will `JOIN` still be better to use?

Comment: Eh?  Is the teacher moving to a different department?  Or some other action?

Comment: Well, I have to update the `teacher.chief` so that:
head of faculty is a chief for head of department; head of department is a chief for ordinary teacher

Comment: A `person` can have many roles (teacher/chief/head/...)?  So, you need a `person` table, plus `roles` table.  `roles` could have `person_id` and `role`, and the pair of columns is the PK.  (Or something in that direction.)

Comment: I have to work with this structure (tables in question are trimmed to keep only relevant columns). The situation is the following: if `teacher.id` is set in `faculty.headFK` - this teacher is considered to be head of faculty; if `teacher.id` is set in `department.headFK` - this teacher is considered to be head of department.
I updated my question and wrote a code which I came up to, thanks to your initial answer and this code works as I need it to.